# Rails - using dropdown to pass id of object into session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, drop-down-menu, action

At the moment, I have a list of projects in the projects/index view. What the user currently has to do is click 'Show' on the project, then click 'Select Project'. This calls a custom action I've created in the controller, which passes the id of the project into the session, so only relevant tasks etc. are shown in the following pages.

What I want to happen is to have a dropdown menu on the index view, with a list of all the projects. Then, when the submit button is clicked, it will pass the id of that project into the session, exactly the same. I've tried every way I can think of doing this, but I can't get anything to work - mainly because it appears as if the id of the project isn't getting passed from the dropdown.

My question is - how can I get the submit button to call a custom action that will take the id from the dropdown menu's project and pass that into the session?

I don't know if I need to add the code to the index action of the controller, or whether the submit button can call the custom action. I'm pretty new to rails, so the more people can spell stuff out, the better!!

Here's the projects/index:

```
<%= form_for(@project) do |f| %>
  <% if @project.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@project.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this project from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @project.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= f.hidden_field :company_id, :value => session[:company_id] %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
  <%= collection_select :project, :id, Project.all, :id, :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit 'Select Project', :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The controller code so far:

```
def index
  @projects = Project.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @projects }
  end
end

def select_project
  project = Project.find(params[:id])
  session[:project_id] = project.id
  redirect_to root_url, notice: "Current project set to: #{project.name}, ID: #{project.id}"
end
```

I can't put

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
```

into the index action, otherwise it says that it can't find a project without an id.

Answer (score 0):

When you are submitting a form this will be done through the either the update or create action in your controller.

May I ask why you are loading your dropdown from session? since you could just use the rails helpers to find (filtered) records using :where etc.

Once you get an array returned as you can list them in your dropdown as option attributes. and submit them to your update or create action. once you are there you can take value's from the submitted hash using

```
params[:key][:nested_key]
```

or just

```
params[:key]
```

While you are doing this here you are even able to bind these to sessions or variables for later use.

Just try to make the flow as robust and easy as you can.

Have fun